# Cannot get index of item in array with Nunjucks for loop

Tags: for-loop, templating, nunjucks

I'm having some trouble getting indexes of a items in an array from a Nunjucks `{% for %}` loop.

The array I am targeting is simple and looks like this

```html
pages[1,2,3]
```

And this is the Nunjucks loop

```html
{% for i,p in data.tickets.pages %}
  {{ i }} : {{ p }}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is

`{{ p }}` outputs `1,2,3` but `{{ i }}` doesn't output anything.

If anyone can tell me how to fix this, I'd much appreciate it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To get the index in a for loop use `loop.index` (loop.index starts with a `1`)
To get the standard behavior (start with a `0`) use `loop.index0`

```js
data.tickets.pages = [1, 2, 3];
```

#### Template code (`loop.index`)

```html
{% for page in data.tickets.pages %}
  {{loop.index}}: {{ page }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Output**

```
1:1
2:2
3:3
```

#### Template code (`loop.index0`)

```html
{% for page in data.tickets.pages %}
  {{loop.index0}}: {{ page }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Output**

```
0:1
1:2
2:3
```

#### See Also the [*nunjucks docs*](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#for)

- **`loop.index`**: the current iteration of the loop (1 indexed)
- **`loop.index0`**: the current iteration of the loop (0 indexed)
- **`loop.revindex`**: number of iterations until the end (1 indexed)
- **`loop.revindex0`**: number of iterations until the end (0 based)
- **`loop.first`**: boolean indicating the first iteration
- **`loop.last`**: boolean indicating the last iteration
- **`loop.length`**: total number of items

Answer (score 1):

Tipically `nunjucks` wait single iterator for `array`.
When you use multi-iterator and pass `array`, `nunjucks` split each `array` element by iterator set.

```
{% set pages = [[10, 11], [12, 13]] %}
{% for a, b in pages %}
{{a}},{{b}}
{% endfor %}
---
10:11
12:13
```

You can use `range`, convert array to object (element order can be lost) or use `loop.index0`'/`loop.index`

```
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();

// range
var res = nunjucks.renderString(`
    {% for i in range(0, items.length) %}
    {% set item = items[i] %}
    {{i}}: {{item}}
    {% endfor %}`, 
    {items: [10, 12]}
);

console.log(res);

// array to object
res = nunjucks.renderString(`
    {% for i, item in items %}
    {{i}}: {{item}}
    {% endfor %}`, 
    {items: Object.assign({}, [10, 12])}
);

console.log(res);

// loop.index0
res = nunjucks.renderString(`
    {% for item in items %}
    {{loop.index0}}: {{item}}
    {% endfor %}`, 
    {items: [10, 12]}
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I was really hoping it would be a more trivial fix in the template without the need for more tinkering with Nunjucks configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here by ways of Google or whatever. I was able to use the method with range loop described above directly in my template, and even nesting loops.

Here's part of my code directly in a nunjucks template:

```
<ul class="index">
    {% for x in range(0, dbReport.sections.length) %}
        {% set section = dbReport.sections[x] %}
        <li>
            <strong>{{ x + 1 }}</strong> {{ section.sectionTitle }}
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <strong>{{ x + 1 }}.1</strong> Section components:
                    <ul>
                        {% for y in range(0, section.subSections.length) %}
                            {% set subSection = section.subSections[y] %}
                            <li>
                                <strong>{{ x + 1 }}.1.{{ y + 1 }}</strong> {{subSection.subSectionTitle}}
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

with [array.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries)

```
{%- for pageIndex, page in collections.pages.entries() -%}
  <div class="page" id="page-{{ pageIndex + 1 }}">
    {{ page.templateContent | safe }}
  </div>
{%- endfor -%}
```